# Fetching most recent data from the table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column called rate in the table which will be updated for each contracts.Every single contract will have multiple rates. So when I write a query by joining multiple tables, I want the rate column to be fetched from the table. but when I run the query it is giving all the rates which are updated.so the contracts are getting duplicated.

I want the query to fetch the most recent updated rate for each contracts. Can anybody suggest an idea of how to do that?

Comment: Add your table structure with sample data,query you tried and expected output.

Comment: Select distinct c.contractoid ,cr.rateamount as ContractRate from dbo.contract c left join contractrate cr on c.contractoid=cr.contractoid

Comment: this is my query.updatedatetime are already added in the rates table

Answer (score 1):

If you have an updatedTime column in contractrate table then you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and take the latest rate for each contract and join it with contract table.

```
SELECT c.contractoid ,x.rateamount as ContractRate 
FROM (
       SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITON BY contractoid ORDER BY UpdatedTime DESC) AS RN
       FROM contractrate ) x
INNER JOIN dbo.contract C ON x.contractoid=c.contractoid
WHERE x.RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save updatedatetime in your rates table and then get query with (Top 1) clause order by updatedate desc.

hope this help

Comment: the rates table already has the updatedatetime column. Please advise how can we get it in query. Below is my query

Comment: Select distinct
c.contractoid
,cr.rateamount as ContractRate
from dbo.contract c
left join contractrate cr on c.contractoid=cr.contractoid